# Understanding of getKey in ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, collections, concurrenthashmap

I am converting an hashmap to ConcurrentHashMap and invoking 16 threads, please see pseudocode as below.
When each thread is processing based on data from db, they look for a condition like `myid` which is a key in ConcurrentHashMap is same `id` data fetched from db. If yes, then I need to perform some business logic. Nowhere in mid of process do I change contents of ConcurrentHashMap.
But, one observation here is that after all threads have completed processing and program ends, few thousand records are ignored.
Please let me know if I am missing anything with respect to understanding of ConcurrentHashMap?

```
public class Producer   {
    // convert an hashmap to ConcurrentHashMap and pass this as an argument for QueueConsumerWorker constructor
    ConcurrentMap<Long, Pair<String, String>> concurrentMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(finalMap);
    
    // Invoke 16 threads of QueueConsumerWorker 
}



public class QueueConsumerWorker implements Callable<Void> {
    @Override
    public Void call() throws Exception {
        ...
        // Get data from db and loop through resultset
        while (rs.next()) {
            ..
            if (concurrentMap.containsKey(myid)) {
                // Perform my business logic i.e. for concurrenthashmap I only perform getKey but do not perform any 
                // updates.
            }
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where and when is data added to the map? If the map is fully seeded with value before the 16 threads are started, then "concurrent" make no difference. The fact that you see a difference would mean that the map is changed *while* the threads are running.

Comment: To clarify: Some records have ids which *are* keys in the Map, but those records are not processed, so `containsKey` must be returning false when those records ids are being checked. Is that a correct statement of what you're seeing?

Comment: You are referring to a method named `getKey` in the title and code comment, but there is no such method in `ConcurrentHashMap`. If the only thing you are ever doing is `containsKey`, there is no point in using a concurrent map at all (as @Andreas already said), in fact, you don’t even need a `Map`, a `Set`, like the `keySet()` of `finalMap` would be enough. However, you can’t use the same `ResultSet` concurrently.